# How would I go about overlaying the gray word 'password' on top of a password box?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, passwordbox

You know how in many WP7 apps you can 'watermark' a textbox to hint at what the user should put inside of it? I want to do that with a password box. It's rather trivial with a text box, I just modify the get and set focus events to handle it all properly, but in a password box the text only shows up as the blocked out dots (except for the last character which is a nice touch).

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking about putting a textbox on top of the password box and hiding it on tap or something but that seems pretty ugly.

Update: I really like the PhoneTextBox control in the silverlight toolkit but it doesn't have any options for passwords. I'm really looking for a PasswordBox with the watermark capabilities. But it's proving much harder to find than I was hoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up doing this technique: http://damianblog.com/2011/01/21/wp7-password-watermark/

It's pretty much what my first gut instinct was, it's a bit cheesy, and someone who's working on the silverlight toolkit should definitely try to implement this sometime.

Answer (score 5):

The "gray overlaying text" on textboxes are commonly referred to as `Watermarks`.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/create-a-watermark-textbox-effect-from-window-phone-7/

Comment: That's a cool tutorial but he still doesn't address the issue of replacing each character with a dot in the password box. I'm pretty sure I can do that myself in the on key pressed event but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Easy way, just download the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) and use the PhoneTextBox control.

You can check usage sample for the control [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-PhoneTextBox-in-depth)!

Comment: This is a really cool control, It's pretty much exactly what I wanted except that they don't have the replacing of the password box's text with dots. Which they do have in the default one

Answer (score 1):

This may also fit your needs :-

http://watermarktextbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Almost, but it still doesn't have that password feature